# Is it possible to point gulp-connect to middleware (i.e. "app.js") file instead of index.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-connect

sorry for a silly question - new to node.js environment and trying to figure out how to setup default entry point to app.js instead of index.html using node.js and gulp-connect for livereload

below code works for index.html in "builds/development" directory

```
 gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: ‘builds/development',
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

Comment: "Gulp plugin to run a *webserver* (with LiveReload)" Are you trying to serve a .js file ?

Comment: yes and trying to setup routes using middleware (via "app.js") - thx